# Error:Declaration of ProfileControllerSetting::cancel() should be compatible with JControllerForm::cancel($key = NULL)

Tags: php, joomla2.5

hey i am new in joomla and making a component called profile. I am getting error in folder controllers/setting.php.
Here's my code;

class ProfileControllerSetting extends JControllerForm {

```
 function save(){
    parent::save();
    if($this->task=='save')     
    $this->setredirect('index.php?option=com_profile');
        }

 function cancel(){     
    $this->setredirect('index.php?option=com_profile');
  }

}
```

the error is coming is:`Strict Standards: Declaration of ProfileControllerSetting::cancel() should be compatible with JControllerForm::cancel($key = NULL)`

and

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of ProfileControllerSetting::save() should be compatible with JControllerForm::save($key = NULL, $urlVar = NULL)
```

please help me .

Answer (score 0):

How your interpreter is telling you already, yo have to parameterise your functions.
Try something like:

```
class ProfileControllerSetting extends JControllerForm { 
     public function save($key = NULL){
        parent::save();
        if($this->task=='save')     
        $this->setredirect('index.php?option=com_profile');
    }

     public function cancel($key = NULL, $urlVar = NULL){     
        $this->setredirect('index.php?option=com_profile');
    }
}
```

Since you cannot simply overload PHP-functions you are extending the class `JControllerForm`. So you have to follow the definition of the function load and save declared in the [`JControllerForm`](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/Application/JControllerForm.html).

Comment: Did you tried to add `NULL` as the default value? Have a look at my answer, i just edited.

Comment: @R.J Please be patient to tell if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

For Joomla 3.6 method save must have two parameters

```
public function save($key = NULL, $urlVar = NULL) {
    parent::save();
    if($this->task=='save')     
      $this->setredirect('index.php?option=com_profile');
}
```